# Uncaught TypeError in Qlik.js when trying to deploy Qlik Sense mashup on server

Tags: javascript, html, qliksense, mashup

I have the following HTML code for a Qlik Sense mashup. This code is running perfectly on my local machine but throws an error whenever I am deploying this on the server. I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError from JavaScript as follows:

[image]

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Search Example - Simple</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://branch.qlik.com/anon/resources/assets/client/client.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sense-search.css"/>
</head>
<body style="width: 80%; margin: 20px auto; font-family: arial;">
<h2>Search Example - Simple</h2>

<p>
  The Search Input and Search results have been added via HTML.
</p>
<sense-search-input id="myInput" mode="visualizations"></sense-search-input>
<sense-search-results id="myResults"></sense-search-results>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://branch.qlik.com/anon/resources/assets/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sense-search.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*  
var config = {
host: window.location.hostname,
prefix: "/",
port: window.location.port,
isSecure: window.location.protocol === "https:"
};
require.config( {
baseUrl: ( config.isSecure ? "https://" : "http://" ) + config.host + (config.port ? ":" + config.port: "") + config.prefix + "resources"
});
*/

var config = {
isSecure: true,
host: "****.abc.com",
port: 443,
prefix: "/"
};
require.config( {
baseUrl: ( config.isSecure ? "https://" : "http://" ) + config.host + (config.port ? ":" + config.port: "") + config.prefix + "resources"
} );

require( ["js/qlik"], function ( qlik ) {
qlik.setOnError( function ( error ) {
    alert( error.message );
} );

var app = qlik.openApp('8435df1b-0473-4fd9-96b4-a488f051ceff', config);
app.model.waitForOpen.promise.then(function(){
   senseSearch.connectWithCapabilityAPI(app);
});

});
/*
var myInput = new SenseSearchInput("myInput");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(myInput.element);
senseSearch.connect(config, function(){
myInput.object.attach();
});
*/
</script>
```

Please help me resolve this issue. I am unable to find a way out.

Comment: Did you really use `host: "****.abc.com"`?

Comment: Obviously not! I just do not wish to disclose the name

Comment: @StefanWalther can you please help me figure out the issue?

Comment: I think it might be a problem within the ```sense-search.js```?
What happens if you comment the line with ```senseSearch.connectWithCapabilityAPI(app);```?

Comment: The error still persists! :(